# How to check for authenticated users on Google Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am building a web site and decided to go pure HTML+JS with full Firebase so I don't have to implement a backend system to test new ideas. The use case for this question is that all users should be authenticated in order to get access to the pages (pretty standard security feature, right?).

To accomplish that, I am taking advantage of Google Cloud Functions to check whether a user is signed in or not before allowing access to the pages.
Here is the code implemented on firebase.json:

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/home.html",
    "function": "home"
  } ]
}
```

Inside the home function, I run the following code to check whether the Id Token is a valid one:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedToken) => {
    const userId = decodedToken.uid;
})
```

The problem I am facing is that the value for idToken is invalid:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect algorithm. Expected "none" but got
> "RS256"

I tried to copy & past the value from result.credential.accessToken, but I still get the same error message.

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
if (result.credential) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
}
});
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you direct the HTTPS requests to your `home` HTTPS Cloud Function.

You should pass the Firebase ID token **as a Bearer token in the Authorization header of the HTTP request**, as explained and demonstrated in the following official [Cloud Function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api).

Comment: Thanks, Renaud Tarnec! I would guess that using a session cookie instead of HTTP header would allow my user to return to the page without the need to authenticate again (as long as the cookie is not expired). Since the first hit (directly from the browser) to a cloud function would not include the Authorization header, the user will need to authenticate every time it tries running the "home" protected cloud function.

Comment: No, you don't need to authenticate for every call. Look at the following [line](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/ece0d62efc4fe58921f9913273d1dc4a96ad9248/authenticated-json-api/public/main.js#L130) of the JS file in the sample: it calls the [`getIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) method, which returns the current token if it has not expired. **Otherwise, it refreshes the token and returns a new one.**

Comment: I think there is a difference between the official sample code and my use case. When the user hits the URL https://MY_DOMAIN/dashboard.html in the browser, the HTTP request will be redirected to a cloud function, hence, there is no opportunity to attach the Authorization header in the HTTP request via JS. As result, the function will always return "UNAUTHORIZED" for the first hit and will redirect the user to the login page. Once logged in, that's the only moment I can attach the Authentication header to the HTTP request so the following calls to the function has the proper Firebase ID Token.

Comment: Ok, it is different from this aspect of first hit, but globally speaking it is the same mechanism that you need to implement if I 'm not mistaking.